# Failing to install msi packages and apps being deleted

Tags: windows-11, windows-installer

### Laptop Specs

Processor   11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-11950H @ 2.60GHz   2.61 GHz

Installed RAM   32.0 GB (31.2 GB usable)

Laptop Make => Dell Precision 7560

OS => W11

### The Problem

On Saturday, Windows prompted me to update and I obliged willingly. But after the update, Windows wouldn't start. It'd would blue screen endlessly and reseting, restore points etc were not working at all. So I installed a clean Windows 11 but failed to install software based on msi.

The error it would show is `Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software.`

So I naturally started digging around on Google and Bing and found that the problem lied with the `msiexec.exe`. I went to services to start the service as in the picture here

[image]

Whenever I'd press Start, the following error would show

[image]

Which made think that it's something to do with Windows. So I reinstalled it again clean then it worked and I installed "some" of my apps but the ugly error has reared its head again. It's still there.

To add insult to injury, it's now deleting apps. For example, Spotify on my laptop when I try to start it, it says

[image]

I did do a disk check, ran DISM commands but it is still here. I don't know what to do now. Please help